# Tangent to conics

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

For finding condition for tangency of any conic, after finding the quadratic equation of points of intersection of tangent and conic, why do we consider equal roots? What is it's geometric significance?

Comment: Tangents touch the curve at only one point, so the equation should have equal real root.

Comment: @user362325 okay got it thanks